# fixed point theorem for homotopic on surface

Tags: general-topology

A surface is defined to be a Hausdorff space with the property that around every point in the space, there is an open neighborhood homeomorphic with an open disc in $\mathbb R^2$.

Now suppose that for such a surface $X$, $f:X→X$ is a continuous map homotopic to the identity. How we can show that $f$ has a fixed point?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for some variant of the Lefschetz theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f_t(x,y)=(x+t,y)$, $f_t, t\neq 0$ is homotopic to the identity but does not have a fixed point.

Suppose that $S$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the group generated by $u(x,y)=(x+1,y)$ and $v(x,y)=(x,y+1)$, $f_t$ induces a map on $g_t$ homotopic to the identity on $S$ and $g_{1\over 2}$ does not have a fixed point.